# Unable to import data into ArcSDE (9.3.1) and PostgreSQL (8.3.0)

Tags: postgresql, import, arcgis

I've just installed ArcGIS Server Enterprise Advanced with ArcSDE and PostgreSQL, on a virtual Windows Server 2008 box.

After installing, I've been trying to import a feature class (stored in a shapefile) into the geodatabase.

In order to do this I've created a connection to ArcSDE (not a direct database connection) using ArcCatalog -> Database Connections -> Add Spatial Database Connection. I've tested the connection successfully.

However, when I run the tool "Feature Class to Geodatabase", I get the following error message:

```
Failed to convert DNorthEnergyRiskMaps\RiskMapsLibraryTests\Resources\ProbabilityTools\TestFacies.shp. ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Database Connections\s2008NE.sde\arcgis.sde.TestFacies 
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

According to [this](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geoprocessing/archive/2008/09/05/Digging-deeper-_2D00_-Troubleshooting-geoprocessing-errors-when-using-ArcSDE-data.aspx) blog post, this error is a generic "catch-all".

The blog post suggests some debugging steps which I've followed. I've had ArcMap create an [intercept file](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?dgmnmdyeinj). However, I'm non-the-wiser after looking at it (users at the ESRI forum says there are no errors in the intercept file). Maybe someone with more experience could interpret it better...

Also, I've scanned through the ArcSDE and PostgreSQL logs... The only reported errors are in the latter log; multiple SELECT queries are failing because the target tables doesn't exist. Some examples:

```
2009-09-29 13:33:38 CEST ERROR: relation "sde.sdb_surveydatasets" does not exist
2009-09-29 13:33:38 CEST STATEMENT: SELECT 1 FROM arcgis.sde.SDB_SurveyDatasets WHERE 1 = 0
2009-09-29 13:33:38 CEST ERROR: relation "sde.sch_dataset" does not exist
2009-09-29 13:33:38 CEST STATEMENT: SELECT 1 FROM arcgis.sde.SCH_DATASET WHERE 1 = 0
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ArcView is restricted to editing in file and personal geodatabases. You need an ArcEditor or higher license to edit ArcSDE.
See the section "Editing with ArcView" on [this page](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=471&pid=466&topicname=Starting_and_stopping_an_edit_session).

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'Feature Class to Feature Class' geoprocessor tool instead of 'Feature Class to Geodatabase'.  Sometimes the individual geoprocessor tools execute differently or report errors differently.

If that doesn't work, try creating a new feature class directly in the SDE workspace and import the schema from the shapefile.  Once it is successfully created, import data into the feature class from the shapefile.

I recommend trying to create a new feature class from scratch and seeing if that works in your PostgreSQL environment first and then work on importing.

Comment: Thanks, trying different tools revealed what the problem was: adding data to ArcSDE with ArcView. Can data be added to ArcSDE only from ArcEditor or ArcInfo?